# Why check box checked id is getting empty in this case

Tags: jquery

When i am selected status as approved and click on a check box and click on delete button , 
i am getting the id as empty

could you please let em know how to resolve this issue

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/31/)

My code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#deletebtn', function(event) {
     var $checked = $('#tablecontent').find(":checkbox:checked");
   if (confirm("Are you Sure to Delete") == true) {
     var ids = [];
     $.each($checked, function(i, e) {
       var status = $(e).parent().parent().find('.label-status').text();
       var filterstatus = $('#filterstatus').val();
       if (!filterstatus) {
         ids.push($(e).attr("id"));
       } else {
         if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selectall' && status == $('#filterstatus').val()) {
           ids.push($(e).attr("id"))
         }
       }
     });

        alert(ids);
   }       

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue :** When you are trying to get the Status of the Row/Record by using Parent method of the jQuery, then it is not actually getting the correct element where you can find the status.

**Solution :** Change the following line of code

```
var status = $(e).parent().parent().find('.label-status').text();
```

to

```
var status = $(e).closest('.AddreqTableCols').find('.label-status').text();
```

Comment: @PreethiJain - Anytime. Can you please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is what you are trying to do, if its not clear enough what is happening, feel free to ask.

```
$("#selectall").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#tablecontent [type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $this.is(":checked"));
});

$("#deletebtn").click(function (e) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) return;

    var $checked = $("#tablecontent [type='checkbox']:checked");
    var ids = $.map($checked, function (chk) {
        return $(chk).attr("id");
    });
    console.log(ids);
    alert(ids.join(","));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/48/

**COMMENT**
If i was assigned to write the same thing, i would set the status as a `data-status` on the checkbox itself to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `status` is always empty. When you select a filterstatus it comes in the new `if` check and `status == $('#filterstatus').val()` will always be false since `status` is empty.

Change your code to:

```
var status = $(e).parent().parent().parent().find('.label-status').text();
```

You forgot an extra `.parent()`.

> Note: You can always use `console.log()` to test if your variables are filled in correctly.